# Why is $(form).submit (e) firing multiple times?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have the following coffeescript function in a rails app

```
if $(".my-form").length 
  $(".my-form").submit (event) ->
    values = {}
    $.each $(this).serializeArray(), (i, field) ->
      values[field.name] = field.value
      return
    console.log(values)
```

The console shows that, on form submit, this function is being run 4 times.

```
Object {utf8: "✓", my_form[my_field]: "my_value"}
Object {utf8: "✓", my_form[my_field]: "my_value"}
Object {utf8: "✓", my_form[my_field]: "my_value"}
Object {utf8: "✓", my_form[my_field]: "my_value"}
```

To the best of my knowledge, there is not other code that would be interacting with this form. Is there an obvious reason why this function would be run multiple times? What should I be looking for to debug this? And what can I do to prevent this?

Comment: Are you calling the `.submit()` handler multiple times? Try with `$(".my-form").unbind('submit').bind('submit'...`

Comment: no (at least I don't think so). the form is being submitted via a mouse click on a submit button. So is it possible that this is registering as multiple submits? I experimented with adding `$(this).unbind("submit")` to the above function to stop multiple submits, but with no effect

Comment: The handler is probably being registered multiple times. Try using `$(".my-form").unbind('submit').bind('submit',function(event)...` - *this is not  in coffeescript syntax*. May be this - `$(".my-form").unbind('submit').bind 'submit', (event) ->`

Comment: Perfect! thanks again @ShaunakD! I had chained `unbind` in the wrong place.

Comment: Great. You can youself post your answer and close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Shaunak D for this answer.

A mouse click on the form submit button appears to call the `.submit()` handler multiple times.

`unbind("submit")` prevents this (provided it is called in the correct place!)

The correct syntax is:

```
$(".my-form").unbind('submit').bind 'submit', (event) ->
  #actions....
```